# A multitude of challenging logarithmic integrals (Second part)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In this post I list another group of integrals from the new preprint ["The derivation of eighteen special challenging logarithmic integrals" by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334598773_The_derivation_of_eighteen_special_challenging_logarithmic_integrals) where they are nicely evaluated.

> The following equalities hold:
>   \begin{equation*}
> i) \ \int_0^1 \frac{x \log ^3(x)\log (1-x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x=\frac{1761}{512} \zeta (5)-\frac{3}{32} \pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{9}{256}\log (2)\pi ^4;
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> ii) \ \int_0^1 \frac{x \log ^3(x)\log (1+x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x=\frac{7}{256}\log (2)\pi ^4+\frac{3}{64} \pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{1215}{512} \zeta (5);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> iii) \ \int_0^1 \frac{x\log^5(x)\log (1-x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x=\frac{129495}{2048}\zeta (7)-\frac{75 }{128}\pi ^2 \zeta (5)-\frac{\pi ^4}{8} \zeta (3)-\frac{33}{512} \log (2)\pi ^6;
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> iv) \ \int_0^1 \frac{x\log^5(x)\log (1+x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x=\frac{31}{512}\log(2)\pi ^6+\frac{7}{64} \pi ^4 \zeta (3)+\frac{75}{256}\pi^2 \zeta (5)-\frac{114345 }{2048}\zeta (7);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> v) \ \int_0^1 \frac{x\log^7(x)\log (1-x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{42010605}{16384}\zeta (9)-\frac{6615}{1024} \pi ^2 \zeta (7)-\frac{105}{64} \pi ^4 \zeta (5)-\frac{\pi ^6 }{2}\zeta (3)-\frac{2193}{8192}  \log (2)\pi ^8;
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> vi) \ \int_0^1 \frac{x\log^7(x)\log (1+x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{2159}{8192}\log(2)\pi ^8+\frac{31}{64} \pi ^6 \zeta (3)+\frac{735}{512} \pi ^4 \zeta (5)+\frac{6615}{2048} \pi ^2 \zeta (7)-\frac{40403475}{16384} \zeta (9).
> \end{equation*}

**Question**: How would you calculate the integrals by using harmonic series? Are these integrals known in the mathematical literature?

For people that took interest in the Problem **11966** from The American Mathematical Monthly,

> \begin{equation*}
>  \int_0^1 \frac{x\log (1+x) }{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x,
> \end{equation*}

you might want to observe that the integrals from this post contain some additional logs, and in a way can be viewed as more advanced integrals of the one from AMM.

The Problem **11966** may also be found in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, and in the same book there is the identity **3.62**, page 97, (possibly new in the mathematical literature) which has been used for the calculation of these integrals in the present preprint.